# Knockout: Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element when refreshing page

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout to bind an MVC view. This works fine the first time but for subsequent refreshes Knockout throws the error:

> Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

This is my binding code (inside Document.Ready), note that I am using setTimeout to run every 25 seconds, this is where the error occurs:

```
function viewModel() {
      Loading = ko.observable(true),
      CurrentUser = ko.observable(),
      Environments = ko.observableArray(),
      CurrentFormattedDate = ko.observable()
   }   

function doPoll() {
             $.get("/home/getindex")
                 .done(function (data) {
                     $(data).each(function (index, element) {
                         viewModel = data;
                         viewModel.Loading = false;
                         viewModel.CurrentFormattedDate = moment().format('MMMM YYYY');
                     });
                     ko.applyBindings(viewModel);                     
                 })
                 .always(function () {
                     setTimeout(doPoll, 25000);
                 })
                 .error(function (ex) {
                     alert("Error");
                 });
            };

            doPoll();
```

How do I avoid the error when DoPoll is called multiple times?

Comment: Why do you use `$(data).each`? You seem to never utilize the `index`/`element` arguments and just update the same object in a loop. The result would be equivalent to not using a loop at all. Also, I the `viewModel` object is wrong. You need to put `this` inside the member initialization, like `this.Loading = ...`, otherwise the supposed members will become __global__ variables, and that is bad practice in JS!.

Comment: Ah, good spot. The model was formerly bound to a collection and I have neglected to update the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, bindings in Knockout may happen only once per dom element. The `ko.aplyBindings` would apply the binding to the document body, thus it will be already bound with data when you call it a second time from the `doPoll` function.

A possible solution is to make your current view model an observable property of a new view model; then only update the observable property:

```
var actualViewModel = {
    innerViewModel: ko.observable(new viewModel());
}   

function doPoll() {
    $.get("/home/getindex")
       .done(function (data) {
           $(data).each(function (index, element) {
                   data.Loading = false;
                   data.CurrentFormattedDate = moment().format('MMMM YYYY');
                   actualViewModel.innerViewModel(data);
               });                  
           })
       .always(function () {
                setTimeout(doPoll, 25000);
           })
       .error(function (ex) {
                alert("Error");
           });
 };

 doPoll();
```

You would need to call the **initial** binding against the new view model:

```
ko.applyBindings(actualViewModel);
```

You will also need to update the way properties are accessed in the bindings, by putting the `innerViewModel` in front - for instance:

```
<div data-bind="text: CurrentFormattedDate">...</div>
```

would have to become

```
<div data-bind="text: innerViewModel.CurrentFormattedDate">...</div>
```