# Knockout.js register multiple components in different contexts

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying register multiple components with knockoutjs but from different contexts in the same app which results in **"Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element."**

What I try to do is calling this from multiple places.

```
knockout.components.register('a-name', {
    viewModel: AViewModel,
    template: { require: 'text!ui/views/a-view.html' }
});

knockout.applyBindings();
```

This works if I register all components in one place and make the applyBindings() once. But this on the other hand causes multiple other problems for me. As I'd like each of components that I register to be independent of each other.

So I can I register components in separate parts of the app?

EDIT: Found this answer: [Knockout: Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element when refreshing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839399/knockout-error-you-cannot-apply-bindings-multiple-times-to-the-same-element-wh)

Which states that ko.applyBindings() can only be called once per DOM element. I dont get the point of that and their documentation is very slim. Is there another way to inject html when needed while using knockout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I register components in separate parts of the app?

No, AFAIK you cannot. Registration has be be done before calling `applyBindings`.

This does *not* imply directly that components have to depend on eachother. You'll need a composition root for the entire app (or at least one per `applyBindings` call / app DOM area) and register *all* components there. The components themselves need no knowledge of eachother, not per say.

Note that this is only about *registering* components. You can still have [asynchronous loading](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#how-knockout-loads-components-via-amd) on demand for the actual components.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a global register function in your buisness logic:

Pseudo Code!

```
function registerAname()
{
    if( knockout.components.contains('a-name'))
        return;

    knockout.components.register('a-name', {
       viewModel: AViewModel,
       template: { require: 'text!ui/views/a-view.html' }
    });

    knockout.applyBindings();
 }
```

class c:
registerAname()

class x: registerAname()

Comment: this is pseudo code check that there is soemthing like the contains method

Comment: Actually the method to check if the component has already been registered is the following: 
if (knockout.components.isRegistered('a-name'))
    return;